# LatLng(N,E) coordinates to Stereographic Projection(X,Y)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I developed an Android app that after some actions saves the coordinates from google maps to a CSV file in the formal Lng(°E),Lat(°N). The issue that i am having is that when I want to transform the coordinates, for example if i have this coordinates: 24.321533203125 E, 45.19829646576477 N i want them to look like this 446847.6161987508 X, 411169.23141073465 Y (Stereo graphic Projection (X(m),Y(m))), i cannot find any class that can be used to perform this transformation(Pulkovo transformation). Can someone please help me?

Comment: As this sounds like a math problem, you should describe what you've tried. Also given that stereographic projection covers a number of transformations you should at least describe what your expected end result of the projection will look like.

Comment: For example if i have this coordinates: 24.321533203125 E, 45.19829646576477 N, this is the form that i save them but i want them to look like this 446847.6161987508 X, 411169.23141073465 Y before i save them. And til now i haven't find a class or a method that does this.

Comment: Well honestly I don't know how anyone can help you if you don't know what type of transformation is occurring. I was looking for more what type of map the projection is trying to render. You should reach out to whomever gave you the problem and get more detail on the type of transformation.

Comment: It is Pulkovo Transformation

Comment: See if this is useful: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/search?q=Pulkovo&unscoped_q=Pulkovo Good luck.